# Conductive liquid, that after evaporation will allow me to use my gloves with a smartphone

Tags: conductivity, gloves

I'm looking for a conductive liquid that, after it evaporates, leaves the material that has been exposed to it conductive.

I'd like to use my smartphone with gloves. I do have a pair of professional, expensive gloves, with "smartphone friendly material" on the index finger-pad, but it works dreadfully. I'd like to use the tip of my finger, and not the finger-pad, to interact with the smartphone surface.

So I thought, let's wet the material in some conductive liquid, let it dry, and done!

I did try this approach with colloidal silver and it does not seem to work.

The next on my list is a solution of water with iron rust ( I am unsure about the effect, but I'd give it a try).

Any other ideas? It must be human-safe. Colloidal silver would be perfect (antibacterial properties) if it could be made to work.

Comment: When conductive liquids go dry, the remaining solid residue is rarely conductive. Try stitching a thin copper wire into the fingertip.

Comment: Possible solution could be achieved with conductive thread/strand - but it requires interaction with the gloves :/

Comment: Personally, I'd suggest something like silver paint. I wouldn't use iron oxides because they're not very conductive.

Comment: This sounds alot like the X Y problem. Please look at this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and make sure you aren't making the X Y mistake in asking a question.